# json data jquery.append formatting issue

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to build a menu for a mobile app (using jQuery Mobile).  I have an .asp page that queries SQL to pull the menu items (one for now, represented below by `json[0].CompanyName`).  It returns as JSON data.  I want to append the value from SQL to the `<ul>` with ID "mylist".  This works and appends the text inside `json[0].CompanyName`, but it does not have the formatting of the hard coded `Item 1` and `Item 2` of the menu.  Why does the formatting from the CSS work for the two hard coded menu items, but not the dynamic one?

```
  <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">  
     <ul id="mylist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" >
     <li><a href="item1.html" >Hard Coded Menu Item 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="item2.html" >Hard Coded Menu Item 2</a></li>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.getJSON("getdata.asp", function (json) {
                    // alert(json[0].CompanyName);
                    $('#mylist').append('<li><a href="#">' + json[0].CompanyName + '</a>    </li>');
                });
            });
        </script> 
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Not seeing the issue. What does your CSS and generated html look like? Do you have a link to a live page?

Comment: What you see above is what I'm seeing when I view the source of the page when it's rendered in the browser.  It seems like the CSS is applied to all the elements on the page and they render as they should...then the script gets fired, the menu item gets applied to the UL but the CSS doesn't get applied to the dynamically added item.  Is there a way to perhaps reload the CSS but only after the script executes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to refresh the `listview` after you append to it:

```
        $(function () {
            $.getJSON("getdata.asp", function (json) {
                $('#mylist').append('<li><a href="#">' + json[0].CompanyName + '</a>    </li>').listview('refresh');
            });
        });
```

This will tell jQuery Mobile to re-initialize the `listview` element to add the proper CSS classes to the proper elements.

Documentation can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html (At the bottom of the page is a section called *Updating lists*)

Sometimes you run into the situation where you're not sure if the `listview` will be initialized yet, you can use this `if/then` to work-around that issue:

```
var $myList = $('#myList');
if ($myList.hasClass('ui-listview')) {
    $myList.listview('refresh');
} else {
    $myList.listview();
}
```

Comment: Holy smokes, that did the trick.  Thanks very much for helping a new guy.  You've made my day.

Comment: @CorbyBender You're welcome. This is a pretty common issue with jQuery Mobile. Also I notice you are using the `document.ready` event to run your code, check-out the top of the Events Docs page: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html